# Spring Boot Allow CORS for 400 BAD REQUEST responses

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, rest, cors

This issue is bugging me from entire day today. I am not being able to read response body when server (Spring Boot) is sending a `400 BAD REQUEST` response.

From the best of my knowledge, the access control headers in the response looks good and client should be allowed to read the body.

Technical details now.

My ReactJs application endpoint is `http://localhost:3000/` which I use in browser to access the web app.

Client (ReactJs) application is sending an OPTIONS request (Preflight) first and server is returning `200 OK` response with below headers.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization, content-type
access-control-allow-methods: PUT, GET, HEAD, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1800
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 25 Apr 2023 10:24:39 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Now the headers from the response of main POST request:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: close
Content-Length: 101
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 25 Apr 2023 11:02:33 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=bloc
```

If I print the response using `JSON.stringigy(...)` then I get an empty object as `{}`.

If I print the response object directly. I see it like.
[image]

Response tab also appears as blank in Chrome Developer Tools (Network tab)
[image]

What I have tried:

1. In postman, response body is returned properly as expected.
2. Added a filter to log response from server side just to verify if it is server is actually sending the response. I can see the expected response printed.
3. Tried Edge. Same issue.
4. Response Body is properly readable for GET requests as well POST requests as long as response status is `200 OK`. I can see the issue is only appearing when server is sending `400 BAD REQUEST` response.

Below is my client-side source code. I do not have anything related to cors in my request.

```
fetch(`${API_ROOT}/xxx/schedule`, {
  method: "POST",
  body: postData,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${context.user.token}`,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
})
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    console.log(response);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw response;
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function (text) {
    console.log(text);
    toast.success("New record is added successfully.");
  })
  .catch(function (error: ErrorResponse) {        
    toast.error(
      <div>
        Error adding Schedule. <br />
        {error.message}
      </div>
    );
    console.log(["Error adding Schedule.", error]);
  });
```

Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: You should read the body after `response.json()` or `response.text()`, not before. Same for the error case.

Comment: @jabaa Had tried the same before. It is actually printing the same object from console.log that is inside catch.

Comment: Can you add a code snippet with `response.json` for the error case?

Comment: @gurkan 5xx is usually for unhandled error. I am purposefully sending 400 response code in case there are some issues with the request processing (handled).

Comment: I tried it and I have to call `.json()` on the response and await it in the error case. That's missing in the code in your question. `throw response` throws the raw response. It's even possible that the body isn't completely sent.

Comment: @jabaa let me try that. But I think this might not work because in every case, I should be able to see response in Dev Tools as I can see for other requests but for this request this part is just blank (screenshot added in question).

Comment: @jabaa your suggestion worked. I was just not focusing on my client side code too much because I was under the assumption (wrong) that if I can't see the response in F12 tool then my javascript code will not be able to see it at all. But after your suggestion applied, the response is appearing in F12 tool as well. Thanks a lot. If you could please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to await the body in the error case, too:

```
fetch(`${API_ROOT}/xxx/schedule`, {
  method: "POST",
  body: postData,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${context.user.token}`,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
})
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    console.log(response);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw response;
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function (text) {
    console.log(text);
    toast.success("New record is added successfully.");
  })
  .catch(res => res.json())
  .then(function (error: ErrorResponse) {        
    toast.error(
      <div>
        Error adding Schedule. <br />
        {error.message}
      </div>
    );
    console.log(["Error adding Schedule.", error]);
  });
```